# How do I fix "object invalid value" with facebook's like button?

Tags: javascript, facebook

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=https%3A%2F%2Fsites.google.com%2Fsite%2Fx1gamesboo%2Ffacebookplugin.xml%3Fattredirects%3D0%26d%3D1

I don't understand why its saying "Object at URL 'h t tp :// ww w . ga mesboo.n et/home'(ignore spaces in url) of type 'website' is invalid because the given value '/_/rsrc/1400727753182/config/customLogo.gif?revision=19' for property 'og:image:url' could not be parsed as type 'url'."
If I don't even have a URL with the given value.
Code is here https://i.stack.imgur.com/6yduN.png 
The only reason I'm making a facebook button this way is so I can add it to my google site
since google sites doesn't allow javascript you have to embed it. Any ways any help will be appreciated. Oh and another thing I can't seem to get the thumbnail to work If anybody can help me out thanks.

Comment: That code should be embedded into the post, not linked as an image.

Comment: When I added the code it looked funny and you would not be able to tell what it was. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

Your og:image:url in that example is relative, it needs to be the full URL including protocol and server (e.g. instead of `/_/rsrc/1400727753182/config/customLogo.gif?revision=19` it should be `https://sites.google.com/site/_/rsrc/1400727753182/config/customLogo.gif?revision=19` or whatever the real image URL is

Comment: Okay how about this http://i.imgur.com/AKUYnvA.png its still giving me an error and I have added the full URL why?                                      https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=https%3A%2F%2Fsites.google.com%2Fsite%2Fx1gamesboo%2Ffacebookplugin.xml%3Fattredirects%3D0%26d%3D1                                                  I have no idea what to do to fix the "object invalid value" & fix the thumbnail.

Comment: it isn't the full URL when I check: `$ curl 'http://www.gamesboo.net/home' | grep 'og:image'`
returns
`<meta paroperty="og:image" content="/_/rsrc/1400727753182/config/customLogo.gif?revision=19" />`